# Relation between a value function of an MDP and a value function of the corresponding latent MDP

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

In paper "[DeepMDP: Learning Continuous Latent Space Models for Representation Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02736)", Gelada et al. state in the beginning of section 2.4

> The degree to which a value function of $\bar{\mathcal M}$, $\bar{V}^{\bar\pi}$ approximates the value function $V^\bar\pi$ of ${\mathcal M}$ will depend on the Lipschitz norm of $\bar V^\bar\pi$ .

where $\mathcal M$ is the [Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process)(MDP) defined in the original state space $\mathcal S$ and $\bar{\mathcal M}$ is the MDP defined in the corresponding latent space $\bar{\mathcal S}$. $\bar\pi$ is a policy defined on the latent space, which can be applied to $\mathcal M$ by first mapping $s\in \mathcal S$ to $\bar{\mathcal S}$.

My question is how they draw the connection between "The degree to which a value function of $\bar{\mathcal M}$, $\bar{V}^{\bar\pi}$ approximates the value function $V^\bar\pi$ of ${\mathcal M}$" and " the Lipschitz norm of $\bar V^\bar\pi$"?